# where should i put the code in C# service

Tags: c#, events, service

I wrote little service that check some folder every minute and send the content to FTP folder. inside the service in **OnStart** method i sets timer for event that runs every minute:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
        aTimer = new Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        aTimer.Interval = 60000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
}
```

The Event:

```
private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    some logic here....
}
```

Now my question: is that ok to invoke onStart method only once and let the event do the rest? or should i run **onStart** method every minute instead of **event**?

Comment: You do not want the service to be starting and stopping each time, therefore OnStart should be called only once. I do no see issue with delegating things to a handler here

Comment: Another option is to use [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.7.2) and let the OS alert you when the folder changes.

Comment: Agreed with adityap and Johnny Mopp. Have you tried changing the content of your folder **several minutes** after launching your service, to check if it behaves as expected?

Comment: Read the docs. OnStart - as the name already implies - is supposed to be run on start of the service (once per start). The docs also say it should return as soon as possible, so you won't run into a timeout issue. So in fact just setting up a worker and start it is what you want.

Comment: thanks guys. you helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application logic which runs every minute, should be inside the event OnTimedEvent.

Read more in Microsoft Documentation here which gives a walkthrough on how to create a Windows Service Application: [MS Docs - Walkthrough: Create a Windows service app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer#define-what-occurs-when-the-service-starts)

> is that ok to invoke onStart method only once and let the event do the rest?

Yes, OnStart should be executed only once, which is when your service is started.

> or should i run onStart method every minute instead of event?

No, OnStart should run only once.

Suggestion: You might want to increase the time interval, if you are expecting a lot of files or if the file size is going to be large.